# How to delete files from sd card?

Tags: java, android, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a file which is stored on the sd card with file.delete method but that only works when the file is stored on the internal storage?

So how can we delete files which are on the sd card?

I tried this:

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

selectedFilePath points to where my file is located and i get the location from 
**Mediastore.Audio.Media.Data**

Answer (score 0):

have you added this permission in Manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Yes i did and the weird thing is when i delete the file it removes it in my app but when i restart my phone it is there again.